# Vue JS - Problem with computed property not updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am quite new with VueJS and I have been having trouble lately with some computed properties which do not update as I would like. I've done quite some research on Stack Overflow, Vue documentation and other ressources but i haven't found any solution yet.

The "app" is basic. I've got a parent component (Laundry) which has 3 child components (LaundryMachine). The idea is to have for each machine a button which displays its availability and updates the latter when clicked on.

In order to store the availability of all machines, I have a data in the parent component (availabilities) which is an array of booleans. Each element corresponds to a machine's availability.

When I click on the button, I know the array availibities updates correctly thanks to the console.log. However, for each machine, the computed property "available" does not update is I would want it to and I have no clue why.

Here is the code

Parent component:

```
<div id="machines">
  <laundry-machine
    name="AA"
    v-bind:machineNum="0"
    v-bind:availableArray="this.availabilities"
    v-on:change-avlb="editAvailabilities"
  ></laundry-machine>
  <laundry-machine
    name="BB"
    v-bind:machineNum="1"
    v-bind:availableArray="this.availabilities"
    v-on:change-avlb="editAvailabilities"
  ></laundry-machine>
  <laundry-machine
    name="CC"
    v-bind:machineNum="2"
    v-bind:availableArray="this.availabilities"
    v-on:change-avlb="editAvailabilities"
  ></laundry-machine>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
 import LaundryMachine from './LaundryMachine.vue';

 export default {
  name: 'Laundry',
  components: {
    'laundry-machine': LaundryMachine
  },
  data: function() {
   return {
    availabilities: [true, true, true]
  };
 },
 methods: {
  editAvailabilities(index) {
    this.availabilities[index] = !this.availabilities[index];
    console.log(this.availabilities);
  }
 }
 };
  </script>
```

Child component:

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h2>{{ name }}</h2>
    <img src="../assets/washing_machine.png" /><br />
    <v-btn color="primary" v-on:click="changeAvailability">
      {{ this.availability }}</v-btn>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
  name: 'LaundryMachine',
  props: {
  name: String,
  machineNum: Number,
  availableArray: Array
  },
  methods: {
    changeAvailability: function(event) {
      this.$emit('change-avlb', this.machineNum);
      console.log(this.availableArray);
      console.log('available' + this.available);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    available: function() {
      return this.availableArray[this.machineNum];
    },
    availability: function() {
      if (this.available) {
        return 'disponible';
      } else {
        return 'indisponible';
      }
   }
  }
 };
</script>
```

Anyway, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Your problem comes not from the computed properties in the children, rather from the `editAvailabilities` method in the parent.

The problem is this line in particular:

```
this.availabilities[index] = !this.availabilities[index];
```

As you [can read here](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating), Vue has problems tracking changes when you modify an array by index.

Instead, you should do:

```
this.$set(this.availabilities, index, !this.availabilities[index]);
```

To switch the value at that index **and let Vue track that change**.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: Thanks ! 

That actually didn't work but i used instead: 

    this.$set(this.availabilities, index, !this.availabilities[index]);

And that works. I was focusing on this computed property but didn't think about the methods, thanks a lot !